# MySQL Table with Foreign Key on Xampp

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have been looking into many posts here and other places but I still can't make it work.

I'm trying to create the following 2 tables on xampp. But I'm having problems in the second with the foreign key, even after added the InnoDB.

Can anyone take a look at the following code and tell me what am i doing wrong in the foreign key part so that xampp doesn't accept the table? Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE fichas (
    id_ficha INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    cod_produto VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    nome_produto VARCHAR(50),
    versao INT,
    data_ficha DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_ficha)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE ident_dangers (
    id_fichas INT NOT NULL,
    class_subst TEXT NULL,
    simb_perigo VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    words_r VARCHAR (200) NULL,
    INDEX (id_fichas),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_fichas) REFERENCES fichas(id_ficha),
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? "*xampp doesn't accept the table*" is not a valid error message.

Comment: Just so you are clear, you're attempting to create tables in MySQL, not in XAMPP. XAMPP is not related to your problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name with "doesnt' acceptin" i was just stating that couldn't create the table, it was given an error, just that.

Comment: @cypher i kown cypher, but i referenced xampp because during my research before posting the problem here i found that xampp, or the phpmyadmin had problems with that if it engine wasn't "innoDB' or something like that, that's why i mentioned it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's already solved as you can see in the answer above.

Comment: I can see that, but you should still have added the error message in the first place.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right, it was important, sorry for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have faced similar error. Usually it comes from having different types on your fields.

Your table `fichas` has:

```
id_ficha INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE
```

To match it your field `id_dichas` on the `ident_dangers` tables should be declared:

```
id_fichas INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

Comment: That's one problem. The other is the comma at the end of the foreign key definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yaroslav, it was really the UNSIGNED missing, thanks a lot.
Yes user714965, that was another little problem, thanks for the alert.

Comment: Yes indeed, I missed the comma. You are welcome @user1511579, that's what SO is about, asking and answering, helping others.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key should be a primary key in another table, plus remove the comma at the end of foreign key line.